# How to debug tomcat webservice?

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2, tomcat6

I'm running two instances of tomcat on the same machine for 2 parts of a  web application(client app and server app). the client has no datastore and uses the server to interact with the database. The server app uses a wsdl web service to listen for GET requests from the client. I get an invalid login everytime I try to login through the client app. If I try to access the LoginService via browser directly I get this error from the catalina logs.

[PhaseInterceptorChain:369] Interceptor for {http://ws.myoscar_server.oscarehr.org/}LoginWsService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No such operation:  (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /myoscar_server/LoginService)

Comment: You're probably have an error on the servlet mappings. Can you post your web.xml?

Comment: Here is my client app's web.xml http://pastebin.com/dQXnEfLL

Here is my server app's web.xml http://pastebin.com/ecLC5CEW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "everytime i try to login."  I think the error you see in the catalina logs is just saying that you are hitting the web service that is listening for only `POST` requests, but with a browser, you are sending a `GET` request.  That error might be throwing you off.  I would first use something like Firefox Poster to send a `POST` request to your service and see what the real error is.

Comment: sorry I edited the question, I meant to say get as opposed to post. For logging in I'm talking about logging in through the client app